# how do i sit the HR on top of the divs? or get rid of the white space?

Tags: html, css

please help me. i just want my two divs to connect and the hr to sit on top where they meet. ive done alot of research and i just cant find the answer im looking for.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
  }

  hr{
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 auto;
      width: 25%;
      align-self: center;
      border-style: dotted;
      border-bottom: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
      border-color: lightgrey;
      border-width: 6px;
  }

  .top-nav{
      background-color: #111;
      height: 75px;
  }

  #top-container{
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(204, 231, 229), rgb(33, 55, 95));
      display:inline-block;
  }

  #middle-container{
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(204, 231, 229), rgb(33, 55, 95));
      display: inline-block;
  }


  .sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .sidebar a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .sidebar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .sidebar .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  .openbtn {
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #111;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: none;
  }
  
  .openbtn:hover {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  #main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
  }
  
  /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <title>Darrell Walker II</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="HomeCss.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xe88a</i> Home</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xe87c</i> About</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xe8a3</i> Contact</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xf041</i> Donate</a>
          </div>
        <nav class='top-nav'>
            <div id="main">
                <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Menu</button>  
            </div>
        </nav>
          
        <div id='top-container'>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div id='middle-container'>
            <p>world</p>
        </div>





          <script>
          function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
          }
          
          function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
          }
          </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please do not spam nonsense text into the question to get by the filters.

Comment: Do you have an image you could share that shows the desired rendered output?

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your hr

```
hr{   
    margin-top: -10px;    
    position: relative;   
    z-index:9;

}
```

Comment: interesting, but a better answer would be to use position:absolute. That way you can place the dots exactly on the border